# Speedtest-cli capture outupt

Tags: python, python-3.x

Been trying to edit the speed test code so that it would show jitter as well I have attempted to research it myself but am not finding anything.
any input would be much appreciated

```
import re
import subprocess
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient

response = subprocess.Popen('/usr/bin/speedtest', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read().decode('utf-8')

ping = re.search('latency.jitter:\s+(.*?)\s', response, re.MULTILINE)
download = re.search('Download:\s+(.*?)\s', response, re.MULTILINE)
upload =  re.search('Upload:\s+(.*?)\s', response, re.MULTILINE)



ping = ping.group(1)
download = download.group(1)
upload = upload.group(1)


speed_data = [
    {
        "measurement" : "internet_speed",
        "tags" : {
            "host": "RaspberryPiMyLifeUp"
        },
        "fields" : {
            "download": float(download),
            "upload": float(upload),
            "ping": float(ping)
            
        }
    }
]
client = InfluxDBClient('localhost', 8086, 'speedmonitor', 'pimylifeup', 'internetspeed')

client.write_points(speed_data)
```

Comment: And what's the problem?  BTW, what do you think `(.*?)` does in a regex that `(.*)` doesn't already do?

Comment: I get this error
[code]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/tes.py", line 13, in <module>
    ping = ping.group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
[/code]

Comment: And you've looked at the output enough to know that you have a line that reads "latency jitter 9.99 ", spelled exactly that way, capitalized exactly that way?

Comment: Run `/usr/bin/speedtest`, for gosh sakes.  If you have modified it as you say, then you should see your "jitter" line in the output.  Have you tested your changes?

Comment: I think I got it will try it but this was the output

b'\n   Speedtest by Ookla\n\n     Server: XXX - XXX, ON (id = XXX)\n        ISP: XXX Cable\n    Latency:        19.78 ms   (1.67 ms jitter)\n\r   Download:   46.85 Mbps (data used: 56.4 MB)                               \n\r     Upload:       6.24 Mbps (data used: 2.5 MB)                               \nPacket Loss:     0.0%\n Result URL: https://www.speedtest.net/   result/c/XX-XX-XX\n'

Comment: OK, so if you want the "jitter" number, you want `"Latency.*\((.*) ms"`.  Or perhaps `"\((.*) ms jitter\)"`.